# Can you use different account from developer's account to submit to app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I am doing an iOS project for a client and they gave me access to their developer program and iTunes Connect (which actually only have one app in store, the one I'm developing). Unfortunately, because my main account has already been associated to another iTunes Connect, I gave them another account which I created just for using their iTunes Connect. When I tried submitting the app to the store for Beta Testflight, it said that I don't have the rights to do so. So, how do I use a different iTunes Connect to submit to the store? If I can't do that, is there any other way besides making a new Apple account and having to ask the client to invite it again to both the developer's program and iTunes Connect (and also setting it up again from making a certificate, provisioning profiles, etc)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PS: I'm not talking about transferring the app (which are mentioned in a lot of other links that I've searched with the same question). I'm not making the fully released app (not yet anyway). I'm just trying to submit for testing since Testflight is now integrated into the iTunes Connect, which is a lousy decision for a lot of reasons, I might add (rant!). Sending the whole code to the client so they can build and submit it themselves is possible but out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with a project.
It worked when i archived the application and uploaded it to iTunes connect using apple's application loader, you can sign in with the account you want to upload the app to.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Comment: Well, in the end, I asked the client to add a new email that I've created. Thanks though.